# OpenAuth & Open Source Projects

Tags: version-control, oauth, open-source

I am working on an open source project that needs to authorize to a service using oAuth 1.0a.  To do this the client app needs to obtain a "key" and a "secret" that is used as part of the authorization handshake.

Question:  Is it safe to check these tokens into my SCM?  If not, how should I handle this?

Update:  The keys I'm referring to here are application specific and the service they are for is [copy](https://www.copy.com/home/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how secret the keys are.

If they're tied to a user account like for AWS, then I would say to absolutely not include them in the SCM.  In that case, the app should check the environment variables to load a key file from the user's directory.

If they're more designed to be per app, then it would reasonable to include the key in the source tree.

Now, if you're developing a library.  It would reasonable to include your key in the source tree under the tests but not to include it the binary distributions.

One thing I will suggest, is that you put the key under different copyright terms than the rest of the library.  That way, if someone forks your code, you can force them to get their own key.

Comment: I ended up not putting the tokens into SCM and loading them from the local user environment.  Thanks for your input